# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) after Deployment Css & Js not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, server, angular2-template, http-status-code-403

1- I have Created a Web application & Locally its Css & Js are working Superbly Fine .

2 -But Now i Deployed my Project on server & the CSS & JS is totally bursted after deployment .
3 -Why this is happening What is the Problem .
the Paths are Correct for the CSS & JS.

Please Help me .

Regards 
**Deepak Dubey(Software Eingineer)**

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP response code of 403 Forbidden means you (the browser) don't have the right credentials to access the ressource.

Then, you may want to check the filesystem access rights AND the web server (IIS in your case ?) on the target environment.

If the ASP files are showing fine, I believe that :

- you put your static ressources (CSS, JS, images) in a not readable directory, or those files are owned by a different user with no permissions to read by others.
- Or, IIS has been told not to provide anything other than *.asp files.

I'm not a Windows regular user and I won't be aware of the specific manipulations to allow those resources to be delivered. If you don't know how to do that, I'll let the next Windows master reader coming here explain it to you.

Anyways, you may want to update your question tags. This has nothing to do with JavaScript or AngularJS, this related to IIS web server and/or filesystem authorizations.